# Find the length of the curve y = $\sqrt{-x(x+1)} - \arctan \sqrt{\frac{-x}{x+1}}$

Tags: integration, derivatives, arc-length

I used the formula for this example:

$\displaystyle L = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx$

And I start by computing the derivative:

\begin{align*}
y' &= \left(\sqrt{-x^2-x}\right)' - \left(\arctan \sqrt{\frac{-x}{x+1}}\right)' \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{-x^2-x}} \cdot (-2x-1)-\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{-x}{x+1}}\right)^2+1} \cdot \frac {1}{2\sqrt{\frac{-x}{x+1}}} \cdot \frac{-1}{(x+1)^2} \\
&= \frac{-2x-1}{2\sqrt{-x^2-x}} - \frac{1}{{\frac{-x}{x+1}}+1} \cdot \frac {1}{2\sqrt{\frac{-x}{x+1}}} \cdot \frac{-1}{(x+1)^2} \\
&= \frac{-2x-1}{2\sqrt{-x^2-x}}+ \frac{1}{2(x+1)^2 \sqrt{\frac{-x}{x+1}}\left(1-\frac{x}{x+1}\right)}
\end{align*}

but I stopped at this moment because it does not seem to me that this derivation was so complicated, how to do it then? Maybe I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Your derivative is correct. Note, however, that $1-\tfrac x{x+1} = \tfrac 1{x+1}$.

Comment: From the first to the second line, there is a missing $-$ sign in front of the $2x$. It does make it back in later though.

Comment: Oh right, thank you @amsmath !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your actual task it might be beneficial to substitute $z = \sqrt{\tfrac{-x}{x+1}}$. Then your curve is $y = \tfrac z{1+z^2}-\arctan(z)$. Note that you will also have to adapt the boundaries.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Sorry for no replying. Should I simplify my derivative (but I don't know how)?:

$\frac{-2x-1}{2\sqrt{-x^2-x}} + \dfrac{1}{2\left(x+1\right)^2\sqrt{-\frac{x}{x+1}}\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)}$

Because I think without if, it will be a huge overkill when the time for expiation will come.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. Get rid of this $x$ bullshit (it's correct but looks messy) and use the above substitution. Then you can derive much easier.

Comment: Ooh right, it's much simplier now.  But I don't know how this: $y = \tfrac z{1+z^2}$ (when $z = \sqrt{\tfrac{-x}{x+1}}$ ) equals to this 
$\sqrt{-x(x+1)}$ . Maybe it's too late but it's getting me frustrated :/

Comment: Can I really describe it in this form? Wolfram says they are not equal:
https://imgur.com/TPrKEzL
wth is happening

Comment: This is just basic algebra:$$z^2 = -\frac x{x+1} = -\frac {(x+1)-1}{x+1} = -1+\frac 1{x+1}\,\Longrightarrow \frac 1{z^2+1} = x+1.$$Thus$$\sqrt{-x(x+1)} = \sqrt{\frac{-x}{x+1}(x+1)^2} = z(x+1) = \frac{z}{1+z^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that you had problems with the simplifications of derivatives. Let $y=A-B$
$$A=\sqrt{-x (x+1)}\implies A'=\frac{-2 x-1}{2 \sqrt{-x (x+1)}}$$
$$B=\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{-\frac{x}{x+1}}\right)\implies B'=\frac{\frac{x}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{x+1}}{2 \sqrt{-\frac{x}{x+1}}
   \left(1-\frac{x}{x+1}\right)}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x+1}-1}}{2 x}$$
$$y'=A'-B'=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{-x (x+1)}}\implies 1+(y')^2=\frac 1 {1+x}$$
I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Why do you just repeat what OP wrote? Their derivative is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Yup, I often have problems with the simplifications, and I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Actually, I have a question. How did this equation work out? 

I wrote it this way: $-\dfrac{1}{2\left(x+1\right)^2\sqrt{-\frac{x}{x+1}}\left(1-\frac{x}{x+1}\right)}$

And you wrote it this way: 

$\dfrac{\frac{x}{\left(x+1\right)^2}-\frac{1}{x+1}}{2\sqrt{-\frac{x}{x+1}}\left(1-\frac{x}{x+1}\right)}$

Comment: How did you do that?